# ASP.NET Authentication to persist when redirecting to Paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have a website that when the user registers, it creates the account, logs them in and then redirects them to Paypal to take a payment then Paypal returns them back to my site. However when the user returns to mysite, they are no longer authenticated. Can anyone tell me how I can make the authentication persist when returning from Paypal as I don't want the user to have to login straight after they have registered.

I am quite new to asp.net, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Show some code. How do you log the person in?

Comment: Hi ZippyV. I'm not sure I have much relevant code to show. I am logging them in using the standard out of the box CreateUserWizard method. So other than the control that is in the Register.aspx, I don't have any of my own code to log them in. I know this all works though as when I step through the code in development, everything works as it should. Its just that when the site is live, it doesn't behave the same.

Comment: Also thought might be worth adding in case they are related. I had a similar issue with losing seeion variables when redirecting to paypal. This seems to be a common problem and I went down the route of storing these items in a db and then pulling them back out when returning from Paypal which I had read others do to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of authentication do you use? Forms authentication, Windows etc. Show us your web.config. Also make sure that the `cookieless` setting is set to the right value for your authentication. If you use a cookie, then your users will remain logged in after coming back from PayPal. A sample forms authentication setting is attached below:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
          protection="All"
          timeout="30"
          name=".ASPXAUTH" 
          path="/"
          requireSSL="false"
          slidingExpiration="true"
          defaultUrl="default.aspx"
          cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
   </authentication>
 </system.web>
```